# I can not boot Ubuntu unless I disconnect everything from USB 3.0 port

Tags: boot, usb, dell-vostro

Few days before, I have upgraded my OS from 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit (I had the same problem on 13.10). Ever since that, when I try to boot my notebook with any USB cable connected to USB 3.0 port, the screen just remains black and nothing happens and I have to reboot my notebook by force(holding power button). With no cable connected, Ubuntu loads just fine and connecting anything to USB 3.0 is not an issue anymore.

I guess, that it freezes before the kernel is loaded, because when I tried to reboot the computer using alt + screen + b, nothing happened.I was experiencing these difficulties even on the previous version, but just sometimes. 
I am running DELL Vostro 3750.

Please, does anyone have any idea, what may be causing this?

Edit: Maybe I should have also included note, that it freezes after I choose in grub boot menu, what should be booted. But not promptly after I select it. For about 5 seconds computer seems to be doing something (disk control is blinking).

**EDIT:** As requested, I am posting output from sudo blkid:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="499931f2-2f83-4353-8160-9a48a5ee1878" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="f0ad1205-6b52-4990-bb7b-543d53d969c5" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="RezervovM-CM-!no systM-CM-)mem" UUID="E03EB4FA3EB4CAB4" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb2: UUID="EE2AC63D2AC60317" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb4: LABEL="Data" UUID="8CC631C4C631AEF8" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb5: UUID="babe1371-f48f-4b95-a93a-360bcec268b3" TYPE="ext4"
```

and my grub.cfg is avalible here: http://sharetext.org/Vvob

Comment: have you checked the boot priorities/sequence?

Comment: No, I have not. Where I can do that? And what am I looking for?

Comment: When you power ON your system, your fist screen will be your chipset screen in your case you will see DELL screen where you will see a prompt/function key for entering in to Setup. it can be either the "DELETE" or a function key(example 'F2') button. Check that out and once you are there move to "BOOT" and see the options set over there for boot priority 1,2..

Comment: Well the first one is Hard drive and second removable drive... I do not think, that there is the problem

Comment: How many storage devices you have ? After connecting the USB show output of `sudo blkid` and `cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: You mean after I log in, alright?

Comment: Sometimes I got the same. But the same happened to me on Windows 7 too. I think it's related to some BIOS config/conflict, and not to the OS.

Comment: Well I have dual boot and for windows it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that this is a BIOS issue?

I know my dell XPS laptop has several different USB settings in BIOS, but I don't currently have access to my laptop to see what they are (I'll post again later).

In the meantime, try resetting your BIOS to defaults, on Dells I think the option is F9 (from bios settings menu, labeled 'Setup Defaults').

Comment: I am sorry but that did not work. I reset bios to defaults but the problem remains.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a common problem with that model of Dell:

source:http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19407689.aspx

There is a design flaw on the motherboard. If it is still under warranty then send it back. You shouldn't have to do any of the things suggested in these post.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As soon as I confirm, in cooperation with Dell techSupport, that it actually is this kind of problem, I will accept your answer.